# JPA downcasting with treat

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following entities hierarchy:

```
A
|-- B
|-- C
|-- D
```

B, C and D extends A entity. In B and C I have one attribute "name" and I would like to create a query from A entity but I want to retrieve the attribute "name" if it exist. If it doesn't exist or the attribute has null value, null should be returned.

As far as I know I could use the "treat" feature from jpa (we are using eclipse link 2.5).

I am using this query:

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(A.class);

        Root root = query.from(A.class);

        Root rootB = cb.treat(root, B.class);
        Root rootC = cb.treat(root, C.class);

        Selection selection = cb.array(
                rootB.get("name"),
                rootC.get("name")
                );

        CriteriaQuery where = query.select(selection);

        List resultList = em.createQuery(where).getResultList();
```

but the SQL generated is not what it is expected:

```
SELECT name, name FROM A WHERE ((DTYPE IN (?)) AND (DTYPE IN (?))))
```

What is the best way to create this query ? In my real scenario there are many subclasses of A so I would like to avoid to make one query for entity.

I know I could to two queries one for retrieve the entity A, look for its isInstanceOf and make another query. I would like to know if there is a way to make only one query.

Thanks

Comment: TREAT is used to limit and filter the values returned to the subclass specified, so it will not work in the way you want if used on the root or in the select clause.  You would be better to add the 'name' attribute to A and make it inaccessible to the application except through C and B instances.